# Google Sheets NORMDIST( x, mean, standard deviation, cumulative T/F) to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Google Sheets has the NORMDIST( x, mean, standard deviation, cumulative T/F) function. I have not been able to find something equivalent in JavaScript. The examples I've found do not allow for all the variables that are in the Google function or I don't have the understanding to implement them.

I am trying to write a reiterative JavaScript function to replace a set of reiterative Google Sheets calculations and need something like this;

```
x = NORMDIST(x,0,1, TRUE);
y = NORMDIST(x,0,1, FALSE);
```

Comment: Could you provide some more details on what you're trying to achieve? (Data sets, sample sheet, etc.). Do you have an issue with the built-in formulas?

Comment: I am working on an Implied Volatility (IV) formula for stock option pricing. What I have now is an Excel IV formula that starts with an IV guess. It calculates a new IV. That new IV is the new guess for the same formula on the next row.  Usually after 3-5 iterations the new result is the same as the guess. I did find code on GitHub that generates very similar, but not the same results as I get in Excel   The GetHub code also ERRs out occasionally where my Excel code never does.

In my model NORMDIST(x,0,1, TRUE) is used to calc Vega, NORMDIST(x,0,1, FALSE) is used to calc Black Scholes

Answer (score 2):

At a high-level, there's two things that the `NORMDIST` function can do: calculate the Normal Distribution's [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) when `false` is supplied as the last parameter and [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) when `true` is supplied.

The PDF part is easy: just follow the formula given on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) for Normal Distribution.

The CDF part is less trivial as it's a non-elementary integral. Your best shot is to find some open-source implementation and translate it into JS. (Preferably a non-iterative one.) It won't be 100% exact due to roundoff errors, but it can get you extremely close. I found one [here](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/c_src/asa066/alnorm.c).

Here's what I came up with:

```
function _getNDistPDF(x, mean, stdev)
{
  const sqrt2PI = Math.SQRT2 * Math.sqrt(Math.PI);
  let frac = (x - mean) / stdev;
  return Math.exp(-.5 * frac * frac) / (sqrt2PI * stdev);
}

// Adapted from https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/c_src/asa066/alnorm.c
function _getNDistCDF(x, mean, stdev)
{
  const a1 = 5.75885480458;
  const a2 = 2.62433121679;
  const a3 = 5.92885724438;
  const b1 = -29.8213557807;
  const b2 = 48.6959930692;
  const c1 = -0.000000038052;
  const c2 = 0.000398064794;
  const c3 = -0.151679116635;
  const c4 = 4.8385912808;
  const c5 = 0.742380924027;
  const c6 = 3.99019417011;
  const con = 1.28;
  const d1 = 1.00000615302;
  const d2 = 1.98615381364;
  const d3 = 5.29330324926;
  const d4 = -15.1508972451;
  const d5 = 30.789933034;
  const ltone = 7.0;
  const p = 0.398942280444;
  const q = 0.39990348504;
  const r = 0.398942280385;
  const utzero = 18.66;

  let up = false;
  let value;
  let y;

  // For non-standard NDist
  let z = (x - mean) / stdev;

  if (z < 0)
  {
    up = true;
    z = -z;
  }

  if (ltone < z && (!up || utzero < z))
  {
    value = !up * 1;
    return value;
  }

  y = 0.5 * z * z;

  if (z <= con)
  {
    value = 0.5 - z * (p - q * y 
      / (y + a1 + b1 
        / (y + a2 + b2 
          / (y + a3))));
  }
  else
  {
    value = r * Math.exp(-y) 
      / (z + c1 + d1 
        / (z + c2 + d2 
          / (z + c3 + d3 
            / (z + c4 + d4 
              / (z + c5 + d5 
                / (z + c6))))));
  }

  if (!up)
    value = 1 - value;

  return value;
}

function NDistJS(x, mean, stdev, cumulative)
{
  return cumulative 
      ? _getNDistCDF(x, mean, stdev)
      : _getNDistPDF(x, mean, stdev);
}
```

This gives you a function `NDistJS` that takes the exact same parameters as `NORMDIST`.

- The PDF is 100% accurate to the Sheets formula.
- The CDF is 99.9999992% accurate to the Sheets formula for (x=1, m=0, s=1).

Comment: Thank you!  This is way over my head but I've become adept at copy and paste.